# How to delete specific column values in multiple "insert into" query

Tags: sql

Sorry if you think my question is too basic, because i'm a newbie.

Lets say i have 1000 lines of query like this

```
INSERT INTO table (column1,column2,column3) VALUES (1,2,3);
INSERT INTO table (column1,column2,column3) VALUES (3,33,333);
....
```

I want to delete column2 with its value, Is there any way so that i dont need to delete 1000 rows manualy. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with delete the column, do you want to remove the column from the table or do you mean you want to delete the data in the column?

Comment: i want to delete the column and its data, thanks for replying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want to completely drop the second column:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP COLUMN column2;
```

Although you may have used many statements to build up the data in your table, dropping a particular column only requires a one-liner.